# How to play animation first and then after that do some thing?

Tags: java, android-studio, animation

Hey guys I'm super duper new to Android Studio and I'm doing a kind of dice game. So here is the problem when i click the button it should play the animation(animation.xml, dice 1-6 like a rolling dice effect) and then it should display the random dice between 1-6 but it ignores(i guess) the animation and displays random dice immediately so i wanna play the animation first and then display random dice whenever i click the button

animation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d1"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d2"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d3"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d4"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d5"
        android:duration="200" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/d6"
        android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

here is the animation and random dice code

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this animation just doesn't displays 
            animationDice.start();
            //and this code executes immediately 
            playerScoreInt = rollDice(diceRoll1ImageViewPLAYER, diceRoll2ImageViewPLAYER);
            playerScore.setText(Integer.toString(playerScoreInt));
            cpuScoreInt = rollDice(diceRoll1ImageViewCPU, diceRoll2ImageViewCPU);
            cpuScore.setText(Integer.toString(cpuScoreInt));
            winnerChecker();
        }
    });
}
```

When i click the button i wanna
1 animation appears
2 random dice appears
and i can do them separately but when i combine them in one event just random dice appears no animation

Comment: and sorry for my bad English

Comment: You need to provide more information and code snippets because it is impossible to help You right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you mean.

If you want the number on the dice to be changed about how many second, and eventually will have the final result, you can use `CountDownTimer`.

```
// finish in 3 seconds, 100 millisecond made 1 time
new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {
    Random random = new Random();
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // random in 100 millisecond 
        mainBinding.tmp.setText(random.nextInt(6) + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // final result
        mainBinding.tmp.setText(random.nextInt(6) + "");
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a callback. To animate something in android using Kotlin you could try something like this:

```
view.animate()
   .rotation(90f)
   .scaleY(2f)
   .withEndAction(() -> {
        ... code here
    })
    .start();
```

If you need further informations check the documentation: [withEndAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: its Animation Drawable